# Handle to window for PropertySheet

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2015, propertysheet, cpropertysheet

The below code, creating a Property Sheet, works without problem in an Application File.

```
.......

CProp_Sheet Pr_Sheet(_T("PS"));

CPr_Page_1 Pr_Page_1;
CPr_Page_2 Pr_Page_2;

Pr_Sheet.AddPage(&Pr_Page_1);
Pr_Sheet.AddPage(&Pr_Page_2);

m_pMainWnd = &Pr_Sheet;

int nResponse = Pr_Sheet.DoModal();
```

However, when I put the same code in a DLL, and call it from a menu item in another Application, `m_pMainWnd` cannot be used (the menu in the Application is to remain visible behind the Property Sheet).

I have tried to create a handle

CWnd* m_pWnd = &Pr_Sheet;

and use `m_pWnd` in the CProp_Sheet constructor, but although compiling correctly at run time failure always occurs at

```
CProp_Sheet::OnInitDialog().
```

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: Setting m_pMainWnd is only needed when you have a stand alone dialog base application. Just forget this code line. What is the error you receive? Where do you receive the error? Call Stack?

Comment: The code sample you provided is too vague. For people helping you, they need to know more about what classes CProp_Sheet, CPr_Page_1, CPr_Page_2, and the body of your OnInitDaialog.